# Undelete files on an ext4 partition in-place

Tags: data-recovery, undelete

I've just removed most of the files in my home directory accidentally, using `rm -f` command. Anyway, I searched and found some of the tools for recovering deleted files, like *extundelete*, *foremost* and *photorec*. The problem is that I don't have an extra partition to specify as the output-dir to save the recovered files to. All of my hard disk is in one partition and it's the one I'm trying to recover. And on the other hand, the files to recover are pretty huge.

So my question is, how can I recover deleted files into the same partition as the original files? Does any of the tools available recover files in place? I mean hypothetically speaking it must be doable to restore a file pointer into the filesystem without actually copying the file body!? Actually it must be much faster and much easier for an application to do that! (if you ask me)